# Find a nonzero matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ satisfying both conditions at the same time:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Find a nonzero matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ satisfying both conditions at the same time:

$\text{Ker}(A)=\text{span}{((1, -1, -1)^T,(1, 1, -3)^T)}$

$\text{Ker}(A^T)=\text{span}{((1, 2, 4)^T,(0, 1, 1)^T)}$

I have absolutely zero clue on how to solve this question, and it was on my final exam paper last week from linear algebra. Any help is much appreciated!

What I have tried so far:

Writing out $\text{Ker}(A)=\text{span}{((1, -1, -1)^T,(1, 1, -3)^T)}$
as

$x_1 = α + β$

$x_2 = β - α$

$x_3 = α -3β$

But I didn't know how to continue from that. I thought about making a product table, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Do you have access to $\text{Col}(A)=N(A^T)^{\perp}$ ? I assume so since this was on your final.

Comment: Col means column space? If so, then yes, but what is that $N(A^T)^⊥$

Comment: The orthogonal complement of the null space of $A^T$

Comment: Since it is only linear algebra 1, and it is a two semester subject, no I don't know what that is ...

Comment: Find some $v$ that is orthogonal to $\ker A$ and some $u$ that is orthogonal to $\ker A^T$. Then consider $A=u v^T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really haven't yet studied orthogonal complements and etc. it maybe they want you to do it the basic, pretty algebraic (and rather tiring and slightly boring), way: suppose

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix} ;\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1\\\;\;1\\-3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} $$

Now carry on the first multiplication, then the second and equal them (they both equal the zero vector):

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}-a_{12}-a_{13}\\a_{21}-a_{22}-a_{23}\\a_{31}-a_{32}-a_{33}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}+a_{12}-3a_{13}\\a_{21}+a_{22}-3a_{23}\\a_{31}+a_{32}-3a_{33}\end{pmatrix}$$

Denote by $\;R_k\;$ the $\;k\,-$the row, so we get comparing the different rows:

$$R_k: \implies a_{k2}=a_{k3}\;,\;\;k=1,2,3 \implies a_{k1}-2a_{k2}=0\implies a_{k1}=2a_{k2}$$

So substituting $\;a_{12}=x\;,\;\;a_{22}=y\;,\;\;a_{32}=z\;$ ,we get that our matrix looks like

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2x&x&x\\
2y&y&y\\
2z&z&z\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\;x,y,z\in\Bbb R$$

Well, now you use the fact that $\;A^t\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\4\end{pmatrix}=A^t\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\;$

and find and non-zero example of such a matrix $\;A\;$